# AngularJS add incremental value

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to add an incremental identifier to ng-model in AngularJS?

I'm iterating a list of items, and need to and an incremental value to the ng-model="" attribute for each item in the loop, or if there is a simpler way, I'd like to hear it.

What I'm currently trying:

```
            <li ng-repeat="recipe in recipes">
                <label for="cost_ingredient_{{recipe.ingredient_id}}" style="font-size: 16px;">{{recipe.ingredient}}</label>
                <input ng-model="{{recipe.model_name}}" name="formcost_ingredient_{{recipe.ingredient_id}}" type="number" id="cost_ingredient_{{recipe.ingredient_id}}" min="0" step="0.01" value="0" />
            </li>
```

I tried doing this with a directive, but when I call 'formData' in the controller, none of the model indices come up.

I need to pass this information, as part of a form submission back to the next page in the process. This will be deployed to Android, so I'm thinking of just adding this to window.sessionStorage as I only need this once for every time a user runs my app.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$index` property to generate unique ID:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span id="unique_ID_{{ $index }}">{{ item }}</span>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SPeyIb2dGxPpL3yKykr6?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

On iteration, attach an id in the repeater with ng-init. This will modify your original structure and the id will be available outside the repeater.

```
<li ng-repeat="recipe in recipes" >
    <label ng-init="recipe.someId = $index" for="cost_ingredient_{{recipe.someId}}" >
        {{recipe.ingredient}}
    </label>
    <input ng-model="{{recipe.model_name}}" name="formcost_ingredient_{{recipe.someId}}" 
           type="number" id="cost_ingredient_{{recipe.someId}}" 
           min="0" step="0.01" value="0" />
</li>
```

This is similar to Michal Stefanow's answer, except here you actually change the structure by adding an attribute to each item, in this case it's called someId

Another way:

```
<li ng-repeat="recipe in recipes" >
    <label ng-init="recipe.costIngredient = 'cost_ingredient_' + $index" for="{{recipe.costIngredient}}" >
        {{recipe.ingredient}}
    </label>
    <input ng-model="{{recipe.model_name}}" 
           ng-init="recipe.formcostIngredient = 'formcost_ingredient_' + $index" name="{{recipe.formcostIngredient}}" 
           type="number" id="{{recipe.costIngredient}}" 
           min="0" step="0.01" value="0" />
</li>
```

What you'd really want is to pre-process this on the JavaScript side so that it's not evaluated every time:

```
$scope.recipes = [ your array here ];

angular.forEach($scope.recipes, function(recipe, index){

    recipe.costIngredient = 'cost_ingredient_' + index;
    recipe.formcostIngredient = 'formcost_ingredient_' + $index;

});
```

then iterate over that.

P.S. you may want to look into using ng-bind rather than {{ }} to generate the HTML, it's better for unforeseen errors